# Angular Material 2: mdStepper Header icon bg color change

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Is it possible to change the mdStepper step icon background color? I tried this:

```
.mat-step-header .mat-step-icon {
  background-color: #bb092d;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.87);
}
```

But it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [shadow-piercing descendant combinator](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)

```
::ng-deep .mat-step-header .mat-step-icon {
  background-color: #bb092d;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.87);
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/SWbFwv6dXH1lLsBUZeRW?p=preview)**

**Caveats:** `::ng-deep` is deprecated and can be removed in the near feature

Comment: It is worth mentioning that `::ng-deep` is deprecated and the support for this will be dropped soon.

Comment: you can try setting ViewEncapsulation.None in the component and avoid ::ng-deep